# Get all the DOM with webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Im trying to get the html response in my webview, (yes I know that I can do the same without webview).

On my page finished I have this code:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      super.onPageFinished(view, url);
      view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName(\"*\")+'</html>');");
```

The response:

```
<html>[object HTMLCollection]</html>
```

If I try this:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
```

Then this is the response:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What do you have in log? You should insert HTML in a tag not [object HTMLCollection ] or try to append it

Comment: @romuleald Im just getting the response as a string

Comment: So if you have a string you shouldn't use the `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML`